# Selecting a random read from pair of reads in fastq file

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fastq

I have a question about random selection of a read from a sampled pair-end fastq files. I read some topics regarding this manner but none could solve my problem, which is:
I got two fastq files R1.fastq and R2.fastq. What I want to achieve is to randomly sample those files and from each sampled pair of reads I want to randomly select only one read.

What I did so far is...

I sampled my files using seqtk:

```
seqtk sample -s100 R1.fastq 10000 > R1_sample.fastq
seqtk sample -s100 R2.fastq 10000 > R2_sample.fastq
```

then I sorted each file by sequence ID like this:

```
paste - - - - < R1_sample.fastq | sort -k1 -t " " | tr "\t" "\n" > R1_sample_sorted.fastq
```

I did the same with R2_sample.fastq. Then I merged both sorted files so that R1 would be in one column and R2 in the second column:

```
pr -mts R1_sample_sorted.fastq R2_sample_sorted.fastq > merged.fastq
```

the file looks like this:

```
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000 @D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000
TGATGTTTGGATGTAAAGTGAAATATTAGTTGGCG AGCTTTCCTCACTATCTGCTTCATCCGCCAACTAA
+                   +
BBBFFFFFFFFFFFIFFIFFIIIIFIIIFIIFIII B0<FFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000 @D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000
CCTCCTAGGCGACCCAGACAATTATACCCTAGCCA TGTTTAAGGGGTTGGCTAGGGTATAATTGTCTGGG
+                   +
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIBFFIIIIIIIIIII
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000 @D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:1000
TTCTATTTATTACCTCAGAAGTTTTTTTCTTCGCA GTAAAAGGCTCAGAAAAATCCTGCGAAGAAAAAAA
+                   +
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIFIIFIIIFIIIIII BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

And now I want to randomly select only one read from each pair. My initial idea was to use shuf to get a random number from range 1-2:

```
shuf -i1-2 -n1
```

and then somehow select the read cooresponding to the number I got from shuf. For example in the first iteration I got 1 so I pick the read from column 1, in the socond iteration I got 2 so from the next pair of reads I pick the read in the second column etc.

I got stuck here. So my question is, is there a neat way to do this? Maybe with awk or some other method? Any help will be very appreciated.

*Comment to Ashafixs answer:*
**Thanks for your respond and sorry for the huge delay...!** 
I've tested your solutions and they both seem to have flaws.
For the first script I constructed test fastq files R1 and R2 each containing 6 reads. After running the script I expect it to output 6 reads as well (24 lines) in the correct order(ID,seq,desc,qual) but as a set of reads randomly selected from R1 or R2 file. What I got from the script is:

```
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10002:27381 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
AGCTTTCCTCACTATCTGCTTCATCCGCCAACTAATATTTCACTTTACATCCAAACATCAAGATC
+
B0<FFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIFIFIIIIIIIIII
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10004:50631 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10007:32152 1:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
GTAAGGTTAGGAGGGTGTTAATTATTAAAATTAAGGCGAAGTTTATTACTCTTTTTTGAATGTTG
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFFFFFF
```

You can see that the output is not correct. The second read is missing three lines and there should be six reads in total not three. In addition each time I run the script it outputs different number of reads.

For the second script I input a merged fastq file like described above. The output looks similar to the first script output:

```
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10002:27381 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
AGCTTTCCTCACTATCTGCTTCATCCGCCAACTAATATTTCACTTTACATCCAAACATCAAGATC
+
B0<FFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIFIFIIIIIIIIII
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10004:50631 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10004:50631 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
TGTTTAAGGGGTTGGCTAGGGTATAATTGTCTGGGTCGCCTAGGAGGAGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGT
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIBFFIIIIIIIIIIIFFFIIIIIIFIIIIIFIIIFFFFFFFFFFF
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10004:88140 1:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
ACTGTAACTTAAAAATGATCAAATTATGTTTCCCATGCATCAGGTGCAATGAGAAGCTCTTCATC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIFIIIIIIFIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@D3YGT8Q1:297:C7T4RACXX:3:1101:10007:32152 2:N:0:ATGCTCGTTCTCTCGT
CTAGTTTTGACAACATTCAAAAAAGAGTAATAAACTTCGCCTTAATTTTAATAATTAACACCCTC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFIII
```

but this time I always get five reads. Still missing one. And the second and third read headers are the same. This should not happen.

Comment: Did the scripts solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following script (it also works as one liner). First it gets all the headers from your first fastq file, then it randomly picks a fastq file and returns 4 lines from it.
Please note: This only works if both files have identical headers at identical positions.

```
#!/bin/bash
headers=$(grep @ R1_sample.fastq)
var=1
for line in $headers ; do 
  r=$(shuf -i1-2 -n1)
  tail -n +$var "R$r"_sample.fastq |  grep -m 1 -A 4 $line
  var=$((var+4))
done
```

---

Alternatively you could expand your merge and pick a column approach. `cut` is used to remove a random column from the merged output.

```
#!/bin/bash
headers=$(grep @ merged.fastq)
var=1

for line in $headers ; do 
  r=$(shuf -i1-2 -n1)
  tail -n +$var merged.fastq | grep -m 1 -A 4 $line | cut -d$'\t' -f$r
  var=$((var+4))
done
```